# Mapping to already existing database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I am using `Entity Framework 4.1 code first` to connect to an already existing database.  The table that I am using first is called `Bank`.  I also have a `Bank class` as my domain model.  This is how I mapped my class and table:

```
public class HbfContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
          modelBuilder.Entity<Bank>().ToTable("Bank");
     }
}
```

My Bank table:

```
BankID INT
BankName VARCHAR(50)
```

My Bank class looks like this:

```
public class Bank
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I am having issues when I want to return all the banks.  The SQL statement returned from:

```
return db.Banks
     .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

is:

```
SELECT
     [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
     [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
     [Extent1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive]
FROM
     [dbo].[Bank] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY
     [Extent1].[Name] ASC
```

This is not going to work because my table does not have the Id, Name and IsActive columns.  How would I fix this and would EF map BankId to Id and BankName to Name automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instruct EF to ignore `IsActive` property and map other properties. If you don't like data annotations you can do this with fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bank>().Ignore(b => b.IsActive);
modelBuilder.Entity<Bank>().Property(b => b.Id).HasColumnName("BankID");
modelBuilder.Entity<Bank>().Property(b => b.Name).HasColumnName("BankName");
```

Comment: There is no Id and Name columns as you can see in my table structure. So instead of change the domain model's properties would it maybe be wise to map the column names to the properties via fluent API?

Comment: I missed this part. If your class declaration differs from your table you must map all differences. I modified my sample.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following attribute to the IsActive property and see if it helps

```
[NotMapped]
```

**UPDATE**

Use Data Annotations instead of fluent API which is easier to grasp and use IMO

First of all remove the OnModelCreating function from your context class

Then Define your model like this

```
[Table("Bank")]
public class Bank
{
    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("BankName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

This shall work as expected

Comment: I can't see how this will help if the column names in the select don't correspond the column names in the table.

Comment: This is to indicate that the said property doesn't need to be mapped and doesn't exist in the database....Try this, it will solve your problem

Comment: The other thing you need to to do is change your Name property to `BankName` to make sure it matches the corresponding column

Comment: Instead of changing my domain names properties, can't I map the columns to properties using fluent API?

Comment: You can do that but you haven't done anything other than to map your table and Model class...That's why its not able to recognize Whats Name, BankName and other stuff....

Comment: Ok how would I map, for example, Name to BankName using fluent API?

Comment: I would like to stick to fluent API if you don't mind changing your answer :)

Comment: I could change the answer but there is no point since @Ladislav Mrnka has already met this concern....You can use his answer, It works the way you want with fluent API

Comment: It's cool.  Thanks for the help, I'll keep your answer as reference if I need to do it this way some day :)

Comment: Data annotations breaks Single Responsability principle of  Entity class (pattern) and is rudiment from old ActiveRecord antipattern developers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to map the property names to match those in your existing table e.g.

```
    [Column("BankID")]
    [Required]
    public string Id
        {
        get;
        set;
        }
```

Comment: yes I think so, try adding something like modelBuilder.Entity<Bank>().Property(bank => bank.ID).HasColumnName("BankID"); to your DbContext OnModelCreating override.